# PID file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start

Tags: linux, apache, server, centos

I installed httpd 2.4.27 in CentOS 7. I configured httpd.service as systemd service. But everytime I got this error **PID file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.** when I start or restart httpd.service.

Here is my configuration of httpd.service:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=man:httpd(8)
Documentation=man:apachectl(8)

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
ExecReload=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k graceful
ExecStop=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k graceful-stop
PIDFile=/usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Here is the error info:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start httpd.service
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-09-01 22:30:48 EDT; 1s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2173 ExecStart=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2176 (httpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─2176 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
           ├─2177 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
           ├─2178 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
           └─2179 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start

Sep 01 22:30:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 01 22:30:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Sep 01 22:30:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Here is the permission of httpd.pid file:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ll /usr/local/apache2/logs/
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Sep  1 20:46 access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3270 Sep  1 22:30 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5 Sep  1 22:30 httpd.pid
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I found there was no use to change the permission of httpd.pid file manually, because the file will be removed automatically when service gets stopped. And new httpd.pid file will be generated once service is turned on.

Note: I see some posts saying updating /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf will work. But I don't have this file since I installed apache from source. I think only 'yum install httpd' has this.

Anyone can help? I just want to have a clean service start with no error or warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `/lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf` follow:

`d /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid      700 apache apache`

Comment: He states in the question he does not have the /lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf file. So I don't think this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service
```

Add parameter of "ExecStartPost" is work，

```
[Unit]
Description=httpd service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/apachectl -f /etc/httpd/httpd.conf -k start'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/apachectl -f /etc/httpd/httpd.conf -k stop'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/apachectl -f /etc/httpd/httpd.conf -k graceful'
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/chown apache:apache -R /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining where you copied this file from before adding `ExecStartPost`. I think you could also take advantage of `systemctl edit` to avoid needing the copy in the first place: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#edit%20UNIT%E2%80%A6